how to embed Sqlite database with Maui app
This is part question part answer. Ive spent several days trying to find answer to this problem.  Using VS2022 maui targetting androidn and ios. This problem seems to appertain to Android though I havent progress with Ios yet
I post in order to save someone else the 20 hours Ive wasted this week

you have a prefilled SQLite database which you wish to ship with the app
place the mysqlite.db in resources and mark it as 'embedded resource'
under Xamarin simples! accees the sqlite probably using database manager
oops trying to create a connection and query a table results in exception error 'no such table found'
check if file has been copied File.Exists("mysqlite.db") returns true - so VS is copying your file or so you think
further investigation reveals there is a file for sure but it is zero bytes
(you can most easily check the file using Android.Studio device explorer (would be nice to have such a facility in VS2022))
what on earth is happening!
reading around I found several suggestions a) if sqlite doesnt file named file it creates and empty one (but I didnt set the SQLite flags to create!!)  Nevertheless the evidence of the Android.Studio device explorer tells me theres a zero byte file of the same name in /data/0/myappname/files folder where the populated mySQlite.db should be
further reading suggests this is typical google jiggerypockery with secret folders and copies of copies.
Solution!
Dont try to open the file as sqlite first off. right at the start (MainPage in my case) and you only need to do this once as far as I can see - this code seems to populate the  sqlite.db so it can be opened as a databse connection. I dont offer this as a solutions just a wokaround
Please comment if there is a better way of doing it

    stream = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(Constants.DatabaseFilename).Result;
     var mem1 = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(mem1); 
    mem1.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var fs = new FileStream(Constants.DatabasePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    mem1.CopyTo(fs);
    mem1.Close(); 
    stream.Close();
}


The above placed after initialisation of MainPage called just once seems to make opening the database file work App.DB1 = new DatabaseManager(Constants.DatabasePath);
Oh just to explain further the database constants referred to in above code  are same ones used in the database manager - and should explain that the stream is reading from the original embedded file and filestream is writing back to exact same place (android black magic ;-)
 public static class Constants
 {
     public const string DatabaseFilename = "ngar4.db";

     public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
         // open the database in read/write mode
         SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite; //|
         // create the database if it doesn't exist
       //  SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
         // enable multi-threaded database access
       //  SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

     public static string DatabasePath =>
         Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
 }


Sorry have got as far as full CRUD or trying it on iOS sofar it is just a workaround for accessing(reading) data in the embedded file
Hope this saves someone some time
cheers

so have moved on to other aspects of CRUD on this. Well my app happily edits and deletes and re-presents a list view showing changes - trouble is - as you expect next time you reopen the app the sqlite database copies the original and your changes are lost. Hmmmm. Anyone have any ideas?

Can't connect to the database file by configuring application constants?

I din't understand properly as yet as I want a simple way to retrieve the table (as how database works) but this is exactly my problem so I upvote it. Thanks for sharing your experience
